# How to call a function automatically when view is shown in sencha touch 2?

Tags: javascript, view, sencha-touch-2

As the title suggests i need to do things when the view is shown. The function initialize is not helping, it's been called when the whole app is initiated. Maybe somebody can help me?

regards && tia 
  noircc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can bind `painted` event to your view it will work for you.